# .framework file as Carthage (Fabric & Crashlytics example)

Tags: ios, swift, carthage

I'm facing now choosing dependency manager for the second version of my project. I've done my homework and check all dependencies that I will need for **Carthage** support and turns out everything without **Fabric** & **Crashlytics**. For this two I would rather get some extra work than integrate whole cocoapods for that.

So my question is - can I create an example project that i will put on github and make a autobuilding dynamic scheme that allow me to integrate 3rd-party `.framework` files inside my project?

So what my starting point is making a script to check version of pods in a website and check if my downloaded file is in the newest version. That's done. But I have a `.framework` file and how to embedded it in xcode project to support carthage?

Answer (score -1):

@Kuba - you could use the [Xcodeproj gem](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) to modify the project and include the frameworks